# How to pass a parameter to a JAR file called as a parameter to another JAR file?

Tags: hadoop, solr, jar, hdfs, apache-tika

I have a JAR file which has another JAR file as a parameter. The problem is that I want to pass a parameter on the dependency JAR file.

Given below is my command:

```
hadoop jar /opt/lucidworks-hdpsearch/job/lucidworks-hadoop-job-2.0.3.jar com.lucidworks.hadoop.ingest.IngestJob 
-Dlww.commit.on.close=true -Dlw.tika.process=true -libjars /opt/lucidworks-hdpsearch/lib/solr-hadoop-tika-2.2.5.jar 
-cls com.lucidworks.hadoop.ingest.DirectoryIngestMapper -c collection1 -i /user/solr/documents/test.pdf 
-of com.lucidworks.hadoop.io.LWMapRedOutputFormat -s http://localhost:8983/solr
```

I am using a Hadoop Solr connector to use Solr and index some files from HDFS.
This job requires `lucidworks-hadoop-job-2.0.3.jar`. I am passing `solr-hadoop-tika-2.2.5.jar` as a parameter to this JAR because the files that I have are "rich" documents. I need Tika to extract the content of these documents.

Tika by default extracts both the content and the meta-data from the documents. I do not want the meta-data in my case. If I was using Tika alone, I could do something like this:

```
java -jar /opt/lucidworks-hdpsearch/lib/solr-hadoop-tika-2.2.5.jar -T /user/solr/documents/test.pdf
```

This would extract only the content of the document.

I want to give the `-T` argument when I am using Tika with `lucidworks-hadoop-job-2.0.3.jar`.

Is there any way this can be done?

Comment: You shall be calling some function present in Tika jar from lucidworks jar in order to exploit the functionality. In the command, you are only providing dependency. The function should have a mechanism to switch off the Metadata.

Comment: @preeti Do you what this mechanism is? Because that's what I want.

Comment: @preeti I have mentioned in the question that the `-T` argument when calling the Tika JAR alone leads to extraction of the content alone. My question is if there's a way to use this argument when using the Tika JAR as a dependency to `lucidworks-hadoop-job-2.0.3.jar`

Comment: What I am trying to say is that you can not do what you are asking for. You can not pass params like this. And that is not the way its done in jars.  The only way you can change the functionality is by changing the way you are calling the api of Tika . I think you are calling parse function from your code and passing meta parameter. You need to look at documentation of that api and send parameters accordingly.